Why restrict the teaching of forbidden sexual relations?
The Mishnah says:

אֵין דּוֹרְשִׁין בַּעֲרָיוֹת בִּשְׁלֹשָׁה -- One may not expound the topic of forbidden sexual relations before three [or more] people. [Chagigah 2:1]

Why this restriction?  Since the topic is clearly of paramount importance in Judaism, shouldn't the rabbis instruct the people on this matter as much as possible to avoid them sinning?  Why should they wait until they have two people before them?  Don't people need to know?
I don't understand the answers from the commentators I read.  Examples:
-I read: "The danger of expounding upon the verses about forbidden relations in the Torah is either that people will be confused and make irreparable mistakes (i.e. create mamzerim) or that they will be titillated by the attention paid to these verses and they will not be able to control their urges and they will come to sin. " Does not answer my question.
-Also: "If there are only two, the Master speaks to one, and the other listens to him. But if there are three, one listens, and the other two discuss it between them, and can err and come to a wrong conclusion to permit an unlawful thing." Will they always do that? Doesn't the Master hear them?

Sometimes, to understand someone's answer, one needs to try doing it. For example, the second reason implies that it is important that the teacher keeps track and checks what the student understood. However, with two students it is impossible. If a student A answers correctly first,  student B will repeat the answer, not necessarily because he understood. Usually such easy answers get quickly forgotten.

The bigger the crowd, the more likely people are to space out. Someone will walk away thinking they understood it, but they didn't; or with enough information to mess up, but not enough to get it right. Whereas if they didn't know altogether, they would ask.

Personally, I've always understood it to mean that the more people there are, the less serious the atmosphere becomes. I think this is especially true when the students are young and immature, but I find that in a crowd some immaturity can pop up in anyone. Up to two people at a time is the optimal limit.

The Gemara (Chagigah 11b) says that, if there are three (or more) students, then one student can be having a discussion with the teacher while the other students are having their own conversation and miss what the teacher is saying and might then come to permit that which is forbidden; this is particularly a problem with forbidden relations because of the temptation

@Harel13 -- "The more people there are, the less serious the atmosphere becomes".  Are you talking fifth grade class or graduate school class?

To understand this Mishna you need to learn the Talmud on it.

אמר רב אשי מאי אין דורשין בעריות בשלשה אין דורשין בסתרי עריות (בשלשה) מ"ט סברא הוא בי תרי כי יתבי קמי רבייהו חד שקיל וטרי בהדי רביה ואידך מצלי אודניה לגמרא תלתא חד שקיל וטרי בהדי רביה והנך תרי שקלו וטרו בהדי הדדי ולא ידעי מאי קאמר רבייהו ואתו למישרי איסורא בעריות.‏

The conclusion of the Talmud is that this is referring to a specific type of forbidden sexual relations called בסתרי עריות

בסתרי עריות. שאינן מפורשות כגון בתו מאנוסתו ואם חמיו ואם חמותו דנפקי במס' סנהדרין (דף עה.) מדרשא:‏

As Rashi explains, these are forbidden sexual relations that are not explicitly mentioned in the Torah, but are deduced using the classic Talmudic deductive methods.
Other forms of forbidden sexual relations are taught publically, including reading them out aloud on the day everybody goes to services: Yom Kippur!
As stated, the worry is that in a class of 3 students, one student will engage the teacher and the other 2 will start chatting and will miss the finer details, resulting in a wrong ruling.
Does this happen all the time? And why only a subset of forbidden sexual relations?

אי הכי כל התורה נמי עריות שאני דאמר מר גזל ועריות נפשו מחמדתן ומתאוה להם אי הכי גזל נמי עריות בין בפניו בין שלא בפניו נפיש יצריה גזל בפניו נפיש יצריה שלא בפניו לא נפיש יצריה:‏

The Talmud explains that due to human nature, people are attracted to forbidden sexual relations more than to any other sin. For example, the urge to steal something is usually only evoked when one sees an item one fancies.
However, fantasizing about forbidden sexual relations happens even when the object is not around, and sometimes even if the object doesn't exist. Hence the greater worry about misunderstanding lessons referring to forbidden sexual relations.
I think that covers all your questions on the subject.

Hope you don't mind (feel free to revert) but I bolded the main point from the gemara which is the most direct answer to OP's question

@Danny Schoemann -- "These are forbidden sexual relations that are not explicitly mentioned in the Torah, but are deduced".  Forgive me for appearing innocent, but I do not know what these are, and the Gemara does not say.

@MauriceMizrahi:  see Rashi on the Gemara there

@J.W.Tanner -- The daughter or granddaughter of a woman you raped is not permitted?  This is a case that must be taught essentially in private, unlike all the others explicitly in the Torah?  I still don't get it.  For one, the Talmud (ref?) says that we do not concern ourselves with rare cases.  Something is missed by the commentators.

@MauriceMizrahi, as far as I know, the rule that "we are not worried about rare cases" means that the Rabbis do not establish Rabbinical decrees to avert far-fetched and unlikely cases.  But here we are apparently dealing with a Torah prohibition, as Rashi mentions that it is learned from a drasha.  Also, two of the examples Rashi gives are 1) his mother-in-law's mother and 2) his father-in-law's mother.  I don't think those cases are so rare.

@YehoshuaKahan -- Affairs with specific women two generations above yours are "not so rare"?  Boy, I am hopelessly behind the times... :-)

@MauriceMizrahi, the existence of such women is not so rare.  It is not uncommon to marry a woman who still has living grandmothers.

@YehoshuaKahan -- And the men in question frequently have affairs with them?

@MauriceMizrahi, I didn't say that.  I specifically didn't say that.  I went out of my way not to say that.  So there's really no point in querying me on that point.
